# On Log in, my ApacheTomcat webapp goes to webapp/favicon.ico, how can I stop my webapp redirecting to this?

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, favicon

I have a Java webapp running on Tomcat 7.0.54. I am using Spring within the webapp. When a user logs into the /favicon.ico. When the user logs in a second time they are redirected to the correct jsp.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks guys, I tried many quick fixes and got one to work correctly.

I added the following line of code to my login and index jsp pages and it no longer returns the error.

```html
        <link rel="icon" href="data:;base64,=">
```

Thanks Again!

Answer (score 1):

`/favicon.ico` is something which every browser tries to get from any site it visits to display a nice icon in the location bar. My first guess is that your application sends a login-form back to the browser instead of the file or a 404 NOT FOUND.

If you have an icon, make sure browser can download it without logging in first.

Answer (score 0):

Do not blame Tomcat nor your webapp. They give what the browser asked for. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) the file `favicon.ico` is used by browsers to associate an icon to a site. On first connection, the browser gets the file and then caches it until you clear the cache. And you can configure some browsers to clear the cache when the browser is closed.

Answer (score 0):

I just thought I'd congeal the comments here into a coherent answer and solution. I like the question author had this problem.

I protected the site I was developing with a security-constraint url-pattern configuration (e.g. <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>) that blocked the entire site from having access to the contents of my site - including the favicon.ico file. Browsers request the favicon.ico file for the tabs/title bar as a default behavior.

My site had a login page for the FORM authentication that didn't specify a favicon  tag. The security behavior and the browser causes the favicon request to be the first successful action after logging in not your welcome-file! So it displays the favicon.ico to you (or a image not found) once you authenticate.

If you configure your site like I did you may need to eliminate the need to retrieve your favicon from a resource. There are two ways to do this that I can think of: 1) make the favicon image a base64 stored in the <link> element of the login page itself or 2) make the login page not require an image. Both approaches require the use of the <link> element syntax:

```
(no image)

&lt;link rel="icon" href="data:;base64,="&gt;

(image as a data URI)

&lt;link rel="shortcut icon" href="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhIAAgAOf/ADEzMDo0LjY2O9oNHS09P101P1c4NTBCR2A3KHQwO8QaK4otL88aJWw3LL4gJL4gKcAhH5osMT1HO8khKdIeLURGQ9wcJ..." /&gt;
```